# Does computed style give the calculated value which might be different from the actual value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was trying

```
var oldleft = mydiv.style.left; 
mydiv.style.left = "-100%"; 
newleft = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(mydiv,null).getPropertyValue("left"));
```

and the jquery version:

```
var oldleft = mydiv.style.left; 
mydiv.style.left = "-100%"; 
newleft = parseInt($(mydiv).css("left"));
```

on a div. The `mydiv` also uses css3 animations. I thought `newleft` would get the pixel value of `left` property after the div had moved to `-100%`. What I observed was that `newleft` had the same value as that of `oldleft`. So,

> Does computed style give the calculated value which might be different from the actual inline style value?

I want the value of `left` property of `mydiv` in pixels after it would have moved to `-100%`. How do I get this?

**EDIT:** I am posting the minimalistic sample replicating the issue

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">

    .panel-group {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: gray;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        transition: all 0.5s linear;
    }

    </style>

    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"   integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="panel-group">
        Hello
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">

    var center = document.getElementsByClassName("panel-group")[0];
    var initialleft = parseInt($(".panel-group").css("left"));
    center.style.left = initialleft;
    var intpos, increment = 0, lastpos, direction, oldx = 0;
    lastpos = initialleft;
    var pressed = 0;



    center.addEventListener("touchend", function(){

        pressed = 0;
        if( parseInt(increment) > 100 ) {

            center.style.left = (screen.width - 10) + "px";
            lastpos = parseInt(center.style.left);
        }
        else if( (parseInt(increment) < -100) ) {
            center.style.left = initialleft + "px";
            lastpos = parseInt(center.style.left);
        }
        else{
            center.style.left = lastpos + "px";
        }


    });
    center.addEventListener("touchstart", function(down) {

        intpos = down.touches[0].screenX;
        pressed = 1;

    });
    center.addEventListener( "touchmove", function(Dmove) {
            if(pressed == 1) {

            increment = (Dmove.touches[0].screenX - intpos);
            center.style.left = (lastpos + increment) + "px";
        }

        /*
        if (Dmove.pageX < oldx) {
            direction = "left";
        } else if (Dmove.pageX > oldx) {
            direction = "right";
        }           
        oldx = Dmove.pageX; 

        */      
    });

    $(window).on("orientationchange",function(){

        alert("screen is" + screen.width);
        center.style.left = "0px";
        initialleft = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(center,null).getPropertyValue("left"));
        lastpos = initialleft;
        alert(lastpos);
    });

    /* Swiping menu finishes here */


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Open the above code as a html file in google chrome. Then use mobile landscape mode in developer tools. Click the gray box and slide it to right. Now change from landscape mode to potrait mode. AS per the following snippet

```
$(window).on("orientationchange",function(){

            alert("screen is" + screen.width);
            center.style.left = "0px";
            initialleft = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(center,null).getPropertyValue("left"));
            lastpos = initialleft;
            alert(lastpos);
        });
```

`initialleft` should be `0` but it is not. You can check the value of `initialleft` in the console window.

Comment: Could you add some HTML and CSS as well as it seems to be vital to your question?

Comment: In jQuery, you could use http://api.jquery.com/offset/ or http://api.jquery.com/position/

Comment: @AngelosChalaris The html I am using is way too long and irrelevant to the question. You can consider `mydiv` as just an absolutely positioned div.

Comment: jQuery `css()` method returns computed style. If you have issue, please post minimalistic sample replicating issue. EDIT: i just tested it and works as expected, so your issue is somewhere else, especially regarding it: `The mydiv also uses css3 animations`. Now i guess your posted example is not exactly what you are using regarding difference between js and jq version

Comment: @user31782 Your problem revolves around an HTML element with some CSS styling that we have no idea what it looks like or how it behaves. If you want us to replicate the issue and ultimately solve it, you should provide us with more info (i.e. a snippet with just enough code to showcase the problem).

Comment: Wait then. I have to create a dummy code in jsfiddle.

Comment: @A.Wolff I've added the minimal required html to replicate the issue.

Comment: @AngelosChalaris I've added the minimal required html to replicate the issue.

Comment: I'm unable to replicate any issue but i'm not sure what i should expect or not. That's said, your issue has nothing to do with jQuery, right?! And whatever is your issue, is that just while testing it on emulated mobile device or is it the same problem on true mobile device?

Comment: @A.Wolff Its on both. You can see it on the live website http://sycoscientistrecords.github.io/ The value of `initialleft` should be numerically same as `-screen.width` after changing from landscape to potrait(given that the accordian menu/ gray box was pushed to tight). But it is `0`.

Comment: Sorry I have updated the live website. Actually I found a sort of fix.